# VB Web API - Property Name for a Form encoded values with period in name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

Question: 
What should I name a property that is going to be assigned via form-encoded input from an HTTP request, to ensure that the property will be filled in when I create a new instance of the class from form-encoded input that will have some keys that have periods in the name?

I have a VB.NET application that makes use of the ASP.NET self-hosed Web API.

One of the methods accepts input from an application, Bomgar.

The data that's sent in is in a form encoded format, and looks like the following:

```
jump_item.comments=
&jump_item.computer_name=
&jump_item.group=
&jump_item.private_ip=
&jump_item.public_ip=
&jump_item.tag=
&jump_item.type=
&request_id=
&response_url=
&ticket_id=
&user.email_address=
&user.id=
&user.private_display_name=
&user.public_display_name=
&user.username=
```

I'm able to process the 'request_id', 'response_url', and 'ticket_id' portions, by establishing an object that has properties with the same names.

I've done this, because I've read that when accepting this form input and sending the body of the http message containing this data into an object, it will automatically map the form input into properties containing those names.

So I have a class named Ticket, defined as below:

```
Public Class Ticket
    Public Property response_url As String
    Public Property request_id As String
    Public Property ticket_id As String


End Class
```

And I map the content of the form data into an instance of this class via the following within my controller:

```
Public Sub PostProduct(<FromBody()> NewTicketRequest As Ticket)

...

End Sub
```

This correctly assigns the request_id , response_url, and ticket_id properties in that object.

However, I'd like to also capture the jump_item inputs that are being sent, and the user inputs, but I can't include a period in a property name.

How can I include properties in the Ticket class that will be filled in automatically when I pass the HTTP form-encoded data above into a new instance of that object? I'm not sure how to name them, or if I need to somehow set up another object for it.

I'd like to be able to address the user email address in a fashion similar to:

```
NewTicketRequest.user.email_address
```

or

```
NewTicketRequest.user_email_address
```

Even though the item coming in will have a period after the word user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add complex properties to your `Ticket` model. The name of those properties should match the prefix before '.' and the type of those properties should contains properties with name after '.'.

For example to get `jump_item.*` values, your `Ticket` model should contain a property with name `jump_item` which is of a type that contains properties with * names: `comments`, `computer_name`, `group`, `private_ip`, `public_ip`, `tag` and `type`.

**Example**

In below example I added a Model, Controller and a View to the default ASP.NET WebAPI project which I created using Visual Studio.

*Model*

```
Public Class Ticket
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Text As Integer
    Public Property User As ApplicationUser
End Class

Public Class ApplicationUser
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property UserName As String
    Public Property DisplayName As String
End Class
```

*Controller*

```
Public Class ValuesController
    Inherits ApiController

    ' POST api/values
    Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As Ticket)

    End Sub
End Class
```

*View*

```
<form action="/api/values" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="Id" />
    <input type="text" name="Text" />
    <input type="text" name="User.Id" />
    <input type="text" name="User.UserName" />
    <input type="text" name="User.DisplayName" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: This was a fantastic response. I'm not experienced with the whole Model/controller/view side of things; I currently just have a desktop application that uses the ASP.NET Web API. Is the view required?

Comment: This worked spectacularly! I can not thank you enough.

Comment: Could you tell me; If I were to accept a similar input via XML, that had an XML tag that contained a list of objects underneath it, would that involve setting a property on my class as an Array of the objects that would be in the list, and passing the element with the list to that array? Such as <Session_List>, to an array of Sessions that would contain all of the sub properties? I know this is asking a lot but would you be able to tell me how to do that? Or should I set up a separate question?

Comment: I'm not sure about XML, but about GET/POST values which contain nested list of complex objects, you can use the techniques which described in this great post by Phil Haack: [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Comment: By the way, here is a forgotten +1 to your question.